# How to move an element to the mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to move an element when when the user clicks on the document, however, the element is moving to an offset position.  How do I remove the offset when clicking?  I'm trying to get the element to move to the exact position of the mouse, how do I do this?  Would I need to use the `.offset()` function?  If so, how would I do that?

**HTML**

```
Player Name:  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>
<button name="submt" id="meh">Submit</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function(e){
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;
        $("#meh").css("marginLeft", x);
        $("#meh").css("marginTop", y);
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you post the css for these elements too

Comment: I didn't have any css styling set.  Giving it a position of absolute and changing the jQuery css properties fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably much much easier to set its position absolutely and control it with left and top offsets instead of margins:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).on("click", function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var el = $("#meh");
    el.css('position', 'absolute');
    el.css("left", x);
    el.css("top", y);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Player Name:
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<br>
<button name="submt" id="meh">Submit</button>
```

Otherwise, you'd need to calculate the offset based on the previous elements (because the button's offset will change after each click).

Comment: I can't imagine why but it works form me only in case I decrease y value by 50

Comment: That's odd, indeed. Any chance there's a parent element with a 50 margin or something similar to that?

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="soccer-field">
<div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

```
var container = document.querySelector(".soccer-field");
container.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var ball = document.querySelector(".ball");
  ball.style.position = "absolute";
  ball.style.left = `${x}px`;
  ball.style.top = `${y}px`;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use left and top instead, also ensure to use absolute or relative positioning:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).on("click", function(e){
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY;
        $("#meh").css("left", x);
        $("#meh").css("top", y);
    })
})
```